# Open <a href="file:///"> link with finder when browsing directories

Tags: html, macos, finder

Is there a way to have a web browser open file:/// links to directories with finder instead of just listing the files in the browser.

The html page is local running off of the file system so security is not a concern.

The below link gives a directory list of my Documents folder, as expected.

```
<a href="file:///Users/james/Documents">Open documents folder</a>
```

I'd like something like

```
<a href="finder://open?url=file:///Users/james/Documents">Open documents folder</a>
```

Here is an example of a TextMate link that opens a text file. So it should be able to happen.

```
<a href="txmt://open?url=file:///etc/profile">Open /etc/profile file</a>
```

**Update**

Use case:

I am using a html page to provide thumbnails thumbnails and links to a fairly complicated directory structure. The directory structure is on a file server and not a web server. The page just makes it easier to find things.

```
ee/5b/cc/ee5bcc05-d364-4a12-9eec-d386a1725f0b
a3/fa/04/a3fa0420-7907-4435-b8a1-a7048d1fb47a
b4/c6/9c/b4c69c52-8f55-419a-9674-e3131c4f7167
e5/ef/de/e5efde23-8929-4905-99fa-746ac6cf9507
... many more ...
```

Comment: Short answer is, no...Longer answer is maybe you could look into doing something with applescript instead of a webpage?

Comment: I am open to any and all solutions.

Comment: What is the exact use case that you are trying to accomplish? That might be a good place to start. Unfortunately, I haven't done apple script in ages and wouldn't be much help there, I just know that it *can* do things like you are asking.

Comment: I updated the question with a use case. AppleScript is great, but I don't think it will solve this issue on its own.

Comment: Actually i'm searching this from time to time and hope that there is something i haven't found so far :/